# Kotlin how set a button listener to use another button inside it

Tags: kotlin, button

There is a bookbutton and are around 10 buttons in my program each one contains a specific value.

How to make bookbutton save the data depending on what the user choose from the 10 buttons

This is simple code of what I've tried to do to link a button with the bookbutton.

```
    var i = 10
button1.setOnClickListener {

            bookbutton.setOnClickListener {


                i++
                textview.text = "$i"
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please don't completely change your question after someone has attempted to answer it. If you have a new question, you can [ask it separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the *listener* on button2 within the button1 click, not enabling it.

Try to do `button2.isEnabled = true` inside the button1 click listener, and set the button2 click listener outside of it:

```
var i = 10
button2.isEnabled = false // disable by default (you can do this in XML instead)
button1.setOnClickListener {
    button2.isEnabled = true
}
button2.setOnClickListener {
    i++
    textview.text = "$i"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I edited the question it wasn't has enough information. It will work with the edited case as well?

Comment: Your question is still unclear. What do you want button1 to do when pressed? What do you want bookbutton to do when pressed? Where and how did you define other 10 buttons?